# Rspec Faker has_one fail in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I' trying to fix this for hours...

I have this on a controller rspec test:

```
  it "show action should render show template" do
    task = Task.make
    task.mission = Mission.make
    get :show, :id => task
    response.should render_template(:show)
  end
```

But it fails rendering the view because of this:

```
<%=h @task.mission.name %>
```

I don't get it... :/

Comment: What is your specific error message?

Comment: While you are at it, some code from Task or Mission will probably be required as well. Maybe you can see in the trace, where the error comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to change you factories generation :

`task = Task.make(:mission => Mission.make)`

The association mission is not save to Task because you don't save it you can try save task after Mission association

Comment: That's it! It's very logic now. Thanks =)